# Incorrect popover menu position when anchor element is externalized into another component

Tags: material-ui

I'm new to both React and Material-UI. While [examples](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/) work fine and perfectly make sense, they all use inline elements for both triggering button and the menu itself. I want to have some conditionals. For this, I'd rather have a separate component/function that renders this or that. However as soon as I move triggering button into a function, I get

```
Material-UI: the `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.
The anchor element should be part of the document layout.
Make sure the element is present in the document or that it's not display none.
```

I looked through similar questions here, but none of them looked relevant… or I didn't get them:(

Here is the code for modified example where I want to externalize button rendering into a function (to later add conditional and what not)

```
export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const Qqq = () => {
    return (
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Broken Menu
      </Button>
    )
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p> hello</p>
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Qqq />
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the fiddle
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7bnki?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark . I did try to use SO code snippet, but I was getting some error about `https://stacksnippets.net/js` :(

What am I missing to make things work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

placing `Qqq` code  inside `SimpleManu` is causing `Qqq` to remount on every `SimpleMenu` render. 
Because `Qqq` remounted, the anchorEl reference is no longer valid. 
To fix that, move `Qqq` outside `SimpleMenu`.

```
const Qqq = (props) => {
    return (
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={props.handleClick}
      >
        Broken Menu
      </Button>
    )
  }

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p> hello</p>
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Qqq handleClick={handleClick}/>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-iom1j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

---

To see that `Qqq` really re mounts on every `SimpleMenu` render, go to the Code Sandbox and move `Qqq` to be inside `SimpleMenu` like before. 
`useEffect` will print to console on every mount, and you can see what happens.

Comment: Ah! Rookie mistake! Initially, I was unable to access *handleClick* from external function, so I moved it inside, then used *props* to pass handler but didn't try to move the function out again… duh!

Comment: It's not a rookie mistake, when polishing a turd, one's hands always get dirty!